# Is this usage of foreach correct?

Tags: php, foreach

```
<?
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $_SESSION[$key]=$value;
};
?>
```

I am working with databases. I get an user data to `$data`, and then I want to duplicate it to `$_SESSION`, is this code right as I would want to, or has it any type of issue that will provoke it not to work correctly?

Comment: Why not use JSON? You can just use `$_SESSION['some_data'] = json_encode($data);` to store, and `$data = json_decode($_SESSION['some_data'])` to fetch.

Comment: yes you are right,but i want to copy the whole array in which each key corresponds to one key of $_SESSION, and if I do that you are doing, it'll store the whole $data to just one value to $_SESSION[key]

Comment: `$_SESSION = $data;` works with PHP 5.3 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct value assignment to $_SESSION works. I'm using PHP 5.3.

```
<?php
    $data = array('foo' => 'bar', 'key' => 'value', 'k' => 'v');
    session_start();
    $_SESSION = $data;
    $_SESSION['new'] = 'new_value';
    print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
    [key] => value
    [k] => v
    [new] => new_value
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `;` after `}` because a curly braces already is point at begin and end of body, but it's allowed, so your foreach is right. But better use

```
<?
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $_SESSION[$key]=$value;
}
?>
```

Your code with `;` converted by the interpreter in

```
<?
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $_SESSION[$key]=$value;
}
; // There is another empty command line, that is unnecessary
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the unneeded semicolon [that was already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21657013/558021), Yes, this is the correct usage of the `foreach` function if all you want to do is copy over the contents of `$data` into the `$_SESSION` variable.

The only thing to keep in mind is that the `$_SESSION` variable has some limitations regarding what types of variables it can hold. [As mentioned in the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php), the contents of the `$_SESSION` variable are serialized, so you won't be able to store resources in there such as connections to databases. Check out the warning section in the link I posted.